# Retrieving and displaying JSON data from URL (objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, asihttprequest

I am doing my homework to retrieve and display information about current weather from a JSON object using singleton pattern and `ASIHTTPRequest`.

The data from the URL in JSON format looks like this:

```
  { "data": 
        { "current_condition": 
            [ {
             "cloudcover": "51", 
             "humidity": "66", 
             "observation_time": "12:44 PM", 
             "precipMM": "0.0", 
             "pressure": "1002", 
             "temp_C": "30", 
             "temp_F": "86", 


        "visibility": "10", 
         "weatherCode": "116",  
         "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } ], 
         "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png" } ], 
         "winddir16Point": "S", 
         "winddirDegree": "170", 
         "windspeedKmph": "19", 
         "windspeedMiles": "12" } ],  
        "request": [ {
                    "query": "Lat 22.49 and Lon 114.14", 
                    "type": "LatLon" } ],  
        "weather": [ {
                    "date": "2012-06-06", 
                    "precipMM": "0.0", 
                    "tempMaxC": "30", 
                    "tempMaxF": "86", 
                    "tempMinC": "26", 
                    "tempMinF": "79", 
                    "weatherCode": "113",  
                    "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  
                    "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], 
                    "winddir16Point": "SE", 
                    "winddirDegree": "136", 
                    "winddirection": "SE", 
                    "windspeedKmph": "17", 
                    "windspeedMiles": "11" 
                    }, 
                    {
                    "date": "2012-06-07", 
                    "precipMM": "0.1", 
                    "tempMaxC": "30", 
                    "tempMaxF": "87", 
                    "tempMinC": "27", 
                    "tempMinF": "80", 
                    "weatherCode": "113",  
                    "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  
                    "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], 
                    "winddir16Point": "ESE", 
                    "winddirDegree": "121", 
                    "winddirection": "ESE", 
                    "windspeedKmph": "15", 
                    "windspeedMiles": "10" 
                    }, 
                    {
                    "date": "2012-06-08", 
                    "precipMM": "2.1", 
                    "tempMaxC": "31", 
                    "tempMaxF": "87", 
                    "tempMinC": "27", 
                    "tempMinF": "81", 
                    "weatherCode": "116",  
                    "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } ],  
                    "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" } ], 
                    "winddir16Point": "SSE", 
                    "winddirDegree": "166", 
                    "winddirection": "SSE", 
                    "windspeedKmph": "17", 
                    "windspeedMiles": "11" 
                    }, 
                    {
                    "date": "2012-06-09", 
                    "precipMM": "2.8", 
                    "tempMaxC": "32", 
                    "tempMaxF": "89", 
                    "tempMinC": "28", 
                    "tempMinF": "82", 
                    "weatherCode": "176",  
                    "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Patchy rain nearby" } ],  
                    "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png" } ], 
                    "winddir16Point": "SSW", 
                    "winddirDegree": "198", 
                    "winddirection": "SSW", 
                    "windspeedKmph": "17", 
                    "windspeedMiles": "11" 
                    }, 
                    {
                    "date": "2012-06-10", 
                    "precipMM": "13.0", 
                    "tempMaxC": "32", 
                    "tempMaxF": "90", 
                    "tempMinC": "28", 
                    "tempMinF": "82", 
                    "weatherCode": "116",  
                    "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Partly Cloudy" } ],  
                    "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals.png" } ], 
                    "winddir16Point": "SW", 
                    "winddirDegree": "220", 
                    "winddirection": "SW", 
                    "windspeedKmph": "22", 
                    "windspeedMiles": "14" 
                    } ]
    }
}
```

In my AppData.m, the code looks like this:

```
    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
        NSData* responseData = [request responseData];
        NSDictionary* resultDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
        NSDictionary* dataDict = [resultDict objectForKey:@"data"];
        NSArray* myArray = [dataDict objectForKey:@"weather"];

        if(weatherDataArray == nil)
            weatherDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [weatherDataArray setArray:myArray];
}
```

In myWeather.m, the code like this :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        myWeatherDataCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myWeatherDataCell"];


        // get the view controller's info dictionary based on the indexPath's row
        NSDictionary* item = [[AppData sharedData].weatherDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.maxTempLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"tempMaxC"];
        cell.minTempLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"tempMinC"];
        cell.dateLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"date"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;


        NSArray* weatherIconUrl =  [item objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"];
        NSDictionary* value = [weatherIconUrl valueForKey:@"value"];

        NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];

        NSData* url = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        cell.iconView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:url];


        NSLog(@"weatherIconUrl" "%@",urlString);

        return cell;
}
```

The tableview can show

```
    cell.maxTempLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"tempMaxC"];
    cell.minTempLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"tempMinC"];
    cell.dateLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"date"];
```

Except the iconview.image.

I try to use NSlog for

```
 NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value];
```

It can show looks like this:

```
2012-11-11 11:51:46.100 MyWeather[1583:1a603] weatherIconUrl(
    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
)
2012-11-11 11:51:46.101 MyWeather[1583:1a603] weatherIconUrl(
    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0017_cloudy_with_light_rain.png"
)
2012-11-11 11:51:46.102 MyWeather[1583:1a603] weatherIconUrl(
    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
)
2012-11-11 11:51:46.102 MyWeather[1583:1a603] weatherIconUrl(
    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
)
2012-11-11 11:51:46.103 MyWeather[1583:1a603] weatherIconUrl(
    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"
)
```

But when I try to NSLog NSData* url, the result is (null).

So I think I am stuck in when "NSString* urlString" pass the data to "NSData* url".

Comment: Look at the structure of weatherIconUrl -- it has the following punctuation: [ { } ]. What does that mean to you? Is that a dictionary?

Comment: [ { } ] , I guess it means array ?

Comment: Yes, so value is an array not a dictionary. Since it only has one object, you can extract the dictionary by just putting lastObject at the end of the line where you define value.

Comment: Hi, I am still no idea how to retrive the weatherIconUrl URL. Can you explain it more , many thx !

Comment: The same question over and over again - URI + JSON, do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, your variable, "weatheIconURL", is actually an array with one object (a dictionary) in it, so you can use lastObject to fix that line. So those few lines need to be changed to:

```
        NSDictionary* weatherIconUrl =  [[item objectForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"] lastObject];
        NSString* urlString = [weatherIconUrl valueForKey:@"value"];
        NSData* url = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        cell.iconView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:url];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JsonKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)
to parse Jdon data and convert it into dictionary after getting the response from ASSIHTTPRequest 
like this

```
- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// Use when fetching text data


NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

// Json  dictionary
NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [responseString objectFromJSONString];


}
```

in your case if you wanna get the cloudcover you may say

```
     NSString *cloudCover =[[[resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"current_condition"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

hope that helps